# How to filter the partition by result in the same query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am executing the following code in Oracle SQL Dev which is correctly returning all accounts/applications:

```sql
SELECT b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO, COLLATERAL_ID, LOAN_SIZE, CURRENT_BALANCE, processing_date, s.SORT_CODE||s.ACCOUNT_NO, APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE, APPLICATION_ID, DT_OUTCOME,
    row_number ()over (partition by b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO order by APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE desc) as rank
FROM NG1_RR.MCD_CBTL_DATA b, NG1_PSD_TMP.TMP_RMC_APP s
WHERE b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO = s.SORT_CODE||s.ACCOUNT_NO
    and processing_date = '08-JAN-24'
ORDER BY LOAN_SIZE desc;
```

However the 'rank' is returning values of 1-20 and I only want to filter on the 2 latest entries, so where rank in ('1', '2').

Fairly new to this level of SQL query, and I'm currently struggling to work out the answer.

Executed above code and get expected results, however unable to work out how to filter by 'rank' further down the query.

Have tried numerous ways, looking into sub-queries etc (such as below), however all attempts have resulted in failures that I just don't have the expertise to work around:

```sql
SELECT b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO, COLLATERAL_ID, LOAN_SIZE, CURRENT_BALANCE, processing_date, s.SORT_CODE||s.ACCOUNT_NO APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE,APPLICATION_ID,DT_OUTCOME 
FROM ( select b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO, COLLATERAL_ID, LOAN_SIZE, CURRENT_BALANCE, processing_date, APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE,APPLICATION_ID,DT_OUTCOME,
    row_number ()over (partition by b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO order by APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE desc) as rank
FROM ACCOUNT b, APPLICATION s) t
WHERE b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO = s.SORT_CODE||s.ACCOUNT_NO
    and t.rank <=2
    and processing_date = '08-JAN-24'
ORDER BY LOAN_SIZE desc;
```

error returned - `ORA-00904: "S"."ACCOUNT_NO": invalid identifier`

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery attempt

```
SELECT b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO, COLLATERAL_ID, LOAN_SIZE, CURRENT_BALANCE, processing_date, s.SORT_CODE||s.ACCOUNT_NO APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE,APPLICATION_ID,DT_OUTCOME 
FROM ( select b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO, COLLATERAL_ID, LOAN_SIZE, CURRENT_BALANCE, processing_date, APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE,APPLICATION_ID,DT_OUTCOME,
    row_number ()over (partition by b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO order by APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE desc) as rank
FROM ACCOUNT b, APPLICATION s) t
WHERE b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO = s.SORT_CODE||s.ACCOUNT_NO
    and t.rank <=2
    and processing_date = '08-JAN-24'
ORDER BY LOAN_SIZE desc;
```

is getting error

> ORA-00904: "S"."ACCOUNT_NO": invalid identifier

because you are trying to refer to the `s` table alias in the outer query, but that is only in scope inside the subquery.

You've left one concatenation inside the subquery and sort of moved the other one outside, which is a bit odd. If you have both concatenations inside then you can do this, noting that those have to be aliased so they are unique names:

```
SELECT b_SORT_CODE_ACCOUNT_NO, COLLATERAL_ID, LOAN_SIZE,
  CURRENT_BALANCE, processing_date, s_SORT_CODE_ACCOUNT_NO,
  APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE, APPLICATION_ID, DT_OUTCOME 
FROM (
  select
    b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO AS b_SORT_CODE_ACCOUNT_NO,
    COLLATERAL_ID,
    LOAN_SIZE,
    CURRENT_BALANCE,
    processing_date,
    s.SORT_CODE||s.ACCOUNT_NO AS s_SORT_CODE_ACCOUNT_NO,
    APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE,
    APPLICATION_ID,
    DT_OUTCOME,
    row_number () over (partition by b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO order by APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE desc) as rank
  FROM ACCOUNT b, APPLICATION s
  WHERE b.SORT_CODE||b.ACCOUNT_NO = s.SORT_CODE||s.ACCOUNT_NO
  and processing_date = '08-JAN-24'
) t
WHERE t.rank <= 2
ORDER BY LOAN_SIZE desc;
```

though I would change the to modern join syntax, and pass a date value (assuming `processng_date` is actually a date column) instead of relying on implicit conversion and NLS settings:

```
  FROM ACCOUNT b
  JOIN APPLICATION s
  ON b.SORT_CODE = s.SORT_CODE
  AND b.ACCOUNT_NO = s.ACCOUNT_NO
  WHERE processing_date = DATE '2024-01-08'
```

and the partition by doesn't need to be concatenated either, than can be `partition by b.SORT_CODE, b.ACCOUNT_NO order by ...`.

You can also leave them as separate values and concatenate them in the outer query, but you still need to alias them so they are unique:

```
SELECT b_SORT_CODE||b_ACCOUNT_NO, COLLATERAL_ID, LOAN_SIZE,
  CURRENT_BALANCE, processing_date, s_SORT_CODE||s_ACCOUNT_NO,
  APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE, APPLICATION_ID, DT_OUTCOME 
FROM (
  select
    b.SORT_CODE AS b_SORT_CODE,
    b.ACCOUNT_NO AS b_ACCOUNT_NO,
    COLLATERAL_ID,
    LOAN_SIZE,
    CURRENT_BALANCE,
    processing_date,
    s.SORT_CODE AS s_SORT_CODE,
    s.ACCOUNT_NO AS s_ACCOUNT_NO,
    APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE,
    APPLICATION_ID,
    DT_OUTCOME,
    row_number () over (partition by b.SORT_CODE, b.ACCOUNT_NO order by APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE desc) as rank
  FROM ACCOUNT b
  JOIN APPLICATION s
  ON b.SORT_CODE = s.SORT_CODE
  AND b.ACCOUNT_NO = s.ACCOUNT_NO
  WHERE processing_date = DATE '2024-01-08'
) t
WHERE t.rank <= 2
ORDER BY LOAN_SIZE desc;
```

Having said that, as the sort code and account number match, from the join condition, it's unclear why you're including both the `b` and `s` values in your output anyway.

All untested of course, as we don't have your tables or data.